# How to insert data from a script or from a db to Jetpack Compose Room Database?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am creating a affirmation sentences application. This application will show users positive sentences when they scroll the page up or down it will show another affirmation message etc. Sometimes it will send them notification. But to show people these sentences I need to fetch them from somewhere like Room Db. My solution to solve this problem will be directly insert all data to user's local Room DB then fetch all of the sentences without internet connection. But to implement this I need to know is it possible to insert whole script file to db. For example I will have a script file with 100 INSERT query and when I run it it will directly insert 100 data to my local db. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But to implement this I need to know is it possible to insert whole script file to db.

It would likely be simpler to utilise a pre-populated a database and supply that as an asset. However, yes it is certainly possible to use a file with scripts (SQL `INSERT`s).

**Simplicity of a Pre-Populated database**

An SQLite database is (if correctly committed) a single file, that can be copied (typically from the assets folder using the Room's databaseBuilder's [`createFromAsset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createfromasset) method). The data is just read and then written.

To process scripts the data has to be read, processed and inserted probably, as you mention scripts, in a loop. So you have to code a loop to undertake the processing. You also have to do this at the correct time (very likely by overriding the `onCreate` method of a [`CallBack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback)). So more code is required.

However, Room is quite inflexible in regards to the schema. In short it MUST be as expected by Room (or adjusted which would be another coding complexity).

- The simple way to create a database according to Room's expected Schema is to

  1. code the `@Entity` annotated class (the tables), and then
  2. code an `@Database` annotated abstract class with the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotation including all the `@Entity` annotated classes, and then
  3. successfully compile the project, and then
  4. locate the class, that is the same name, but suffixed with `_Impl`, as the `@Database` annotated class, and then
  5. locate the `createAllTables` method, and then
  6. copy the SQL for creating the tables (and other components such as indexes).

**Demo**

The following demonstrates a working example of both, with some 10000 rows of data being loaded for two databases:-

1. senetenc1.db (pre-populated)
2. sentence2.db (populated via "script" i.e. execution of INSERT statements)

The schema for both is exactly the same and is based upon the single `@Entity` annotated class [*Sentence*]:-

```
@Entity
data class Sentence(
    @PrimaryKey
    val sentenceId: Long?=null,
    val sentence: String,
    val usage: Int
)
```

Both `@Database` annotated classes (below) were then created and the project compiled allow the SQL for the creation of the table to be copied from the generated java:-

[image]

At this stage the two data sources, the database and the script file, could easily be generated (same data bar the id for all 10000 rows).

In an SQLite Tool, the following was used:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sentence;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sentence` (`sentenceId` INTEGER, `sentence` TEXT NOT NULL, `usage` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`sentenceId`));
WITH
    cte_counter(i) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT i+1 FROM cte_counter LIMIT 10000)
INSERT INTO sentence (sentence,usage) SELECT 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.',0 FROM cte_counter
;
```

- noting that the CREATE statement was copied from the generated java (as above)

In a Text editor a single insert statement was repeated 99999 times

```
INSERT INTO `Sentence` (`sentence`,'usage') VALUES ('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.',0);
```

The database was closed and then copied into the assets folder (after creating it). Likewise the text file was copied into the assets folder:-

[image]

**Sentence1 `@Database` annotated class** - To handle the Pre-Populated database (asset sentence1.db):-

```
@Database(entities = [Sentence::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class SentenceDatabase1: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getSentenceDao(): SentenceDao

    companion object {
        val TAG = "DBINFO_1"
        private var instance: SentenceDatabase1?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): SentenceDatabase1 {
            if (instance==null) {
                Log.d(SentenceDatabase1.TAG,"Starting Database Build")
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,SentenceDatabase1::class.java,"sentence1.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .createFromAsset("sentence1.db")
                    .build()
            }
            Log.d(SentenceDatabase1.TAG,"Finished Database Build")
            return instance as SentenceDatabase1
        }
    }
}
```

- As can be seen the `createFromAsset` is a simple single line piece of code

**Sentence2 `@Database` annotated class** - To handle the "Scripted" load via the sentence2.txt file:-

```
@Database(entities = [Sentence::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1 )
abstract class SentenceDatabase2: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getSentenceDao(): SentenceDao

    companion object {
        val TAG = "DBINFO_2"
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        private var instance: SentenceDatabase2? = null
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        lateinit var passedContext: Context
        fun getInstance(context: Context): SentenceDatabase2 {
            if (instance==null) {
                passedContext = context
                Log.d(TAG,"Starting Database Build")
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,SentenceDatabase2::class.java,"sentence2.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(cb)
                    .build()
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Finished Database Build")
            return instance as SentenceDatabase2
        }

        val cb = object: RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            @Override
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                val br = passedContext.assets.open("sentence2.txt").bufferedReader()
                br.forEachLine {
                    db.execSQL(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- A CallBack is introduced that overrides the `onCreate` function (a function that is called when the database is created i.e. ONCE for the database's lifetime).
- The function gets the asset and for each line uses as the string passed to the execSQL function, executing the 10000 INSERTs.
- NOTE that for brevity and convenience the main thread is used for the demo. Additionally the context has been obtained in a way that it should not be as it will leak memory.

Finally some activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dbDatabase1: SentenceDatabase1
    lateinit var dbDatabase2: SentenceDatabase2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dbDatabase1 = SentenceDatabase1.getInstance(this)
        dbDatabase2 = SentenceDatabase2.getInstance(this)
        dbDatabase1.openHelper.writableDatabase
        dbDatabase2.openHelper.writableDatabase
    }
}
```

- Note that, again for brevity and convenience, that the database is opened by getting a writeable database (rather than utilise functions in an `@Dao` annotated interface).

  - Just getting an instance of the database does not open the database and therefore would do nothing. i.e. it is not until an attempt is made to open the database that the database is actually accessed and created (if it doesn't already exist) etc

Using **App Inspection** then

[image]

- Sentence1 database has the expected 10000 rows

and

[image]

- Setence2 database also has the expected 10000 rows